# how to move to another screen

Tags: android

I am totally new to android, I have listview, I need in the listOnclick to transfer to another screen but with fading any idea how to do that

what I do now is the following

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about intents http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html